# Shell parenthesis and quotes

Tags: linux, shell

```
find /ABC/ \
    -type f \
    -exec \
    sh -c  ' if [  echo "1" > ${1} ] ; then   if [ "$(cat ${1})" != "1" ]; then [ echo ${1} ]  ; fi ; fi ' _ {} \;
```

My script wanna do this:

find all files in folder. Write 1 to file. Check if "1" is not wrote correctly. print this file's name.

Before. I did this 2 steps. (1) write  (2) read check.
Now I combine these 2 together. Because I want to check immediately after one file is been written.

But my script has something wrong now.
Need help.
Thank you.
It gives my error:

```
sh: 1: unknown operand
```

I guess something is mismatch/ Since I am so non-experienced to shell. Need you guys help

Comment: the File I am manipulating actually is register. One might affects others. So its better to test one by one.

Comment: if you want to echo the file name that was not written successfully why use `then [ echo ${1} ]` instead of `then echo $1` ?

Comment: If you isolate one problem at a time, this would be a better forum. As it is, throwing something with a huge number of bugs over the wall is not particularly reasonable, as it doesn't contribute to having a knowledge base others can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "1" >> "${1}"; if [ "$(cat ${1})" != "1" ]; then echo "${1}" ; fi' _ {} \;
```

I didn't test your command as it didn't look correct from the start.

A few notes, though:

`echo "1" > "${1}"` will clobber the file.  Use `>>` if you want to append.

`[` is a command (also known as `test`.

`then [ echo ${1} ]` uses this test incorrectly.  You don't need a test here.

You don't need `if [ echo...`, as per the other answer, so I took the if test for that out completely.

Comment: thank. I will try tomorrow. I WANT overwrite the file. don't want append :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if [  echo "1" > ${1} ] ; then
> ```

`[` is an ordinary command. It's a builtin in just about every `sh` out there, but it's still parsed normally. So `> ${1}` means “redirect the output to the file whose name is passed as a parameter”. If you want to compare two numbers, use the `-gt` operator:

```
if [ 1 -gt "$1" ]; then …
```

If you want to write `1` to a file, use the `echo` command, not `[ … ]` which is the conditional command (which can also be invoked under the name `test`):

```
if echo 1 >"$1"; then …
```

Note that if `echo 1 >"$1"` succeeds, then it's likely that the file will indeed contain the text you put there. The only time this would not happen is:

- if `$1` was a special file such as a pipe or device (which won't happen since they wouldn't be matched by `-type f`);
- if the lives on a special filesystem where what you read from a file is not what was last written to it — this would be a strange filesystem, not a filesystem for on-disk storage;
- if some other program modified the file in the meantime, which is unlikely due to the small time window but not impossible.